An estimate for $|\lambda^n-1|$ for $|\lambda|=1$ which is not a root of unity
Question
If $\alpha\in (0,1)$ is a Diophantine number, then  for $\lambda=e^{2\pi i \alpha}$ there exists $C>0$ and $s>0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$|\lambda^n-1|>\frac{C}{n^s}.$$
I would like to know if for an arbitrary $|\lambda|=1$ which is not a root of unity we can estimate from below the numbers $|\lambda^n-1|$, in particular does there exists
a contant $C>0$ and $M>0$ such that
$$|\lambda^n-1|>\frac{C}{M^n}.$$
Motivation
Having an entire function $h$ one could need to find an entire function $g$ which satisfies
the equation
$$h(z)= g(z)-g(\lambda z).$$
The positive answer to our question would imply that this is possible.

Of course no, just pick a strong enough Liouville number for $\alpha$, say $\alpha = \sum_{n > 1} \frac{1}{(((n!)!)!)!}$. But this question is not appropriate for MO I think.

@AlekseiKulikov it would be good if you could explain why it's not suitable, also partly for the benefit of people who've never seen such a question in their undergraduate studies.

@DavidRoberts exactly because it was essentially done by Lioville some 180 years ago.

@AlekseiKulikov is this taught in an undergraduate course?

@DavidRoberts depends on which university you are talking about, of course. I learned this in high school, and it was also taught in my undergraduate number theory class.

@adamp may I ask how this question arose? In case you weren't aware, and no one has said this explicitly yet in these comments, MO is intended for questions that arise in the course of original mathematical research (i.e. roughly PhD-level and above). I can certainly imagine someone doing research in a different field and coming across a question of this sort, and not having had the benefit of learning transcendental number theory in high school. I certainly wouldn't have known where to start with your question. Best of luck with the problem!

@AlekseiKulikov age of material is not always a good guide as to whether it is on-topic or not, but you seem to have been particularly blessed in your schooling!

@DavidRoberts together with my colleagues I study the dynamics of weighted composition operators acting on the Frechet space of all entire functions (this belongs to a part of functional analysis which is called linear dynamics). In particular we are interested when such operators are hypercyclic or recurrent. One of the tricks used in this area is explained in the question: having an entire function $g$ one looks for an entire function $h$ which satisfies the equation $g(z)=h(z)-h(\lambda z)$. The solvability of this equation depends on the properties of the sequnce $|\lambda^n-1|$.

@AlekseiKulikov thank you for the comment, you are right: when $\alpha$ is a strong enough Liouville number, then the desired estimate is not satisfied.

@adamp I think a short summary CW answer giving credit to Aleksei would be good, so that the software recognises that this question has been answered and it can be formally accepted. MO has done its job today :-)

In a different direction, but which perhaps may be useful to you, transcendence theory studies the case when $\lambda$ is an algebraic number (but not a root of unity).    Here strong lower bounds for $|\lambda^n-1|$ are known; see for instance the paper of Laurent, Mignotte, and Nesterenko in JNumber Theory (1995).

As noted by Aleksei Kulikov the anwer to the question is negative. In fact, if
$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an arbitrary sequence of positive numbers, then one can easily find an increasing sequence $(n_k)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of natural numbers such that for $$\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-n_k}$$ and every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\left|\left(e^{2\pi i \alpha}\right)^{10^{n_k}}-1\right|<a_{10^{n_k}}.$$
